# windows bash script to find a folder in a server

Tags: windows, bash

I would like to write a script that find a specific folder named **'A'** in several windows servers then copy some files into that folder.

problem is there are many different share drives in the servers and that folder could be in any of them. I end up with a big for loop and numbers of if statement under it. wondering if there is any simple way of doing it. Much appreciated.

JS

Here is a bit of my script only include two of share drives :

```
@echo off
cd /d %~dp0
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion


for /f %%A in (serverList.txt) DO (
if exist \\%%A\S$\A ( 
robocopy  sourcefolder \\%%A\S$\A /e
) else (
if exist \\%%A\e$\A (
robocopy  sourcefolder \\%%A\e$\A /e
) else (
echo %%A has incorrect folder >> errorlog.txt
)

)

endlocal
pause
```

Comment: Show us what did you end up with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose this is a batch (not bash) you will run multiple time, so instread of having a txt with a list of servers you would better use a list of shares that exist, you could adapt this script to produce such a list.

If this is only a one-time convenience script and you just wonder if you could do better, you could just skip the checks and do the robocopy, it will just fail if the targetfolder doesn't exist.

Comment: thanks Peter, seems robocopy will create the directory if it doesn't exist. I will do more research.

Comment: yes, didn't know that, you could use xcopy but my sugegstion to generate a list of existing shares first is better

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks a lot for your help mate. Came up with a similar script to generate the list then copy files there. other way around and works fine!! thanks for your tip mate.